# Iterating through an array of an unknown size C++

Tags: c++, stack, iteration

I'm having trouble with a push-down stack!  I have an array with a maximum size of 10.  I allow the user to input numbers into the stack with push and remove them with pop.  Depending on how many numbers there are in the array, I have to iterate through the stack, which won't always be at a length of 10.  Let's say the stack has 5 numbers (the size of the array is 10) in it.  I need to go iterate through the elements up through element 5, because everything past that isn't a number.  How can I do this?

Comment: Don't you keep top of stack? That's your upper bound, not 10.

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, it should be tagged as so. The `unknown` tag doesn't help at all. People ask questions because *they don't know*. Kinda redundant, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you keep track of how many elements there are on the stack in your C++ class?  When someone calls push, increment the count, and when someone calls pop, decrement the count.

Comment: @ASCII, always easier after you see it for the first time.  If the answer solves your problem, you should click on the check mark over by the voting arrows.

Answer (score 2):

Use std::vector as the underlying storage for your stack and use iterators begin(), end() to get the range of valid element in your vector.